# Want to show only row of selected value with sql and php

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, mysql

I have 40 provider and 10,000 product but i want to show 1 product of each provider

| Brand | Provider | Product | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lightning | Pragmatic Play | Madame Destiny | Link |
| Lightning | Isoftbet | Halloween Jack | Link |
| Lightning | Pragmatic Play | Sweet Bonanza | Link |
| Lightning | Isoftbet | Tropical Bonan | Link |
| Lightning | Netent | Royal Potato | Link |
| Lightning | Netent | Madame Destiny | Link |

SO this my SQL table now. But i want to show 1 item of each Provider like:

| Brand | Provider | Product | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lightning | Pragmatic Play | Madame Destiny | Link |
| Lightning | Isoftbet | Halloween Jack | Link |
| Lightning | Netent | Royal Potato | Link |

this is my code
`

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "newuser1", "p,+Dn@auTD3$*G5", "newdatabse");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Brand='Coolcasino' and Provider IN ('Pragmatic Play','Isoftbet','Netent') ;";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Brand</th>";
                echo "<th>Provider</th>";
                echo "<th>Product</th>";
                echo "<th>URL</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Brand'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Provider'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Product'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['URL'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Please help me if anyboday can`

Comment: And it should be selected 1 data randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance that 1 product show randomly? I mean every time it
> will show a different product instant of showing the first product
> every time

Use row_number :

```
select Brand,
       Provider,
       Product,
       URL
from (   select Brand,
                Provider,
                Product,
                URL,
                row_number() over(partition by Provider order by rand()) as row_num
         from tablename
         where Brand='Lightning' 
         and Provider IN ('Pragmatic Play','Isoftbet','Netent') 
      ) as rand_prod
where row_num=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/BGzx6cYY

*Note*, I suggest not using `select *` , select only the columns which you really need

Comment: wow, you save my day but I also need to filter on Brand because I have a different brand but want to show 1 of them like Brand=Coolcasino or Brand=Schnellwetten. Is it possible? please do the last help

Comment: just want to work this function under https://www.linkpicture.com/q/working.jpg this images link

Answer (score 0):

replace your query with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Brand='Coolcasino' and Provider IN ('Pragmatic Play','Isoftbet','Netent') GROUP BY  Provider;";
```

Comment: Hi @Chandan it works thank you very much. Is there any chance that 1 product show randomly? I mean every time it will show a different product instant of showing the first product every time

Answer (score -1):

Try this if u wish

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Brand='Coolcasino' and Provider IN ('Pragmatic Play','Isoftbet','Netent') GROUP BY  Provider, RAND()";
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. It just show one row not each row

Comment: U just wanted So. Then I didn't get what u wanted. Listen I got it wn I read your question again.I changed my answer.use it and try.then uncheck my negative score

Comment: @ErgestBasha if you would like to provide constructive feedback to new users, that is welcome. Do not be rude and unwelcoming, and do not speculate on other users' votes.